# Formatting a C string

Tags: c, string, hex

I need to send a message in the following format:

`"\x9F\x02\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9A\x03\x15\x04\x24"` (Hexadecimal bytes)

The last three Hexadecimal bytes represent a date.

I need to retrieve the date from the system (Payment terminal) every time I want to send this message, the date given by the system have a string format:

`"150424"`

The problem is that I need to format this date into Hexadecimal Bytes and then concatenate the result with the the rest of the message!

Can any one help me to resolve this problematic?

Comment: Do you know in advance, how long will bee the string you want to send? Also, you could have a look at the %x format string (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: So for the date what you want is [binary-coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) representation?

Comment: `24` would be `\x18` ain't it? And `15` would be `\x0F`. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, all the other bytes  are fixed, the problem is that the date change every day so I need to formate it an then concatenate it with the Rest. I tried to use sprintf with %x but  it gives me the Ascii code in a hexadecimal format ,what I need is the same string in Hexadecimal bytes format! @Attilio

Comment: Use `sccanf` with a format string `%2d%2d%2d` to parse the date string.

Comment: I can't use scanf, @Barmar

Comment: @SaraSara Why can't you? Note that I said `sscanf`, not `scanf`. It parses a string, it doesn't read from `stdin`.

Comment: Yes im sorry  I will try it Thanks @Barmar

Comment: unsigned char day = *(message + 21)

Comment: No, I just want to send the String "150424" in that format "\x15\x04\x24 I don't need to convert the integer 15 in hexadecimal \x0F @Eregrith

Comment: Decimal-to-BCD (and the opposite) is a long solved problem, where you can find many solutions just by searching a little.

Comment: @SaraSara The string "150424" is not equivalent to "\x15\x04\x24". You can't just add `\x` every two char and call that hex

Comment: I know and I tried to copy "\x" every two chars but, I had a compilation error: invalid hexadecimal number @Eregrith

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Ok so now that i understood the problem, here is the answer (I think ^^).

His issue is that he receive the date as a char* (eg. "150424") and he want to produce from those chars => '\x15' '\x04' '\x24'

Here is how I'd do that:

```
int i = 0;
char myStr[23] = "\x9F\x02\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x9F\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9A\x03\x00\x00\x00";

// get today's date
char date[6] = "150424";
int converted = strtol(date, NULL, 16);

myStr[20] = (converted & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
myStr[21] = (converted & 0xFF00) >> 8;
myStr[22] = converted & 0xFF;

printf("[%x", myStr[i] & 0xff);
for (i=1 ; i<23 ; ++i) printf(", %x", myStr[i] & 0xff);
printf("]\n");
return 0;
```

Output

```
[9f, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9f, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9a, 3, 15, 4, 24]
```

---

*Just for info:*

You say you dont need to convert 15 to 0x0F but it sounds weird, cause 0x15 has nothing in common with the 15 from the date then...

So well in case you want to put the decimal instead:

```
char date[6] = "150424";
int converted = strtol(date, NULL, 10);

myStr[20] = (converted / 10000);
myStr[21] = (converted / 100) % 100;
myStr[22] = converted % 100;
```

Then output becomes:

```
[9f, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9f, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9a, 3, f, 4, 18]
```

Hope that helped

Comment: The problem is how can I, after receiving the new date , that format: myStr[20] = '\x15' @Sephizack

Comment: Ah ok so you mean you receive it as a string and you dont know how to convert it to '\x15' ? This is your real issue, just understood. 2sec I'll update my answer then

Comment: It's up to date btw, did it solve your problem ? Or I'm still wrong?

Comment: It's not what I need , but thanks for your response @Sephizack

Comment: ah lol, I really thought I understood this time, what would you like to have at the end in myStr ?

Comment: @Sephizack: `15` is `0x15` in [Binary coded decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Comment: @Jongware I read your link and I don't understand what you mean, From what I understand BInary coded decimals are nothing more than usual binary numbers. Even tho I understand you can create a binary code which represent 15 base 10 as 0001 0101 base 2. But I dont understand why you say 15 is 0x15 in BCD, could you explain?

Comment: A binary coded decimal uses one nibble (4 bits) to store a single digit from 0 to 9 in, and 'A-F' are unused (technically even invalid). It was wildly popular because it allowed comouters to calculate like humans do, instead of that finicky 8-bit 0..255 base. There are even CPU instructions: `aaa`, `aad`, `aam` and so on. Check the Intel manuals if you're interested.

Comment: "\x15\x04\x24" :/  I think that i should convert the date into int, than convert int into BCD format ! @Sephizack

Comment: What I wrote create the "\x15\x04\x24" string and put it at the end of *myStr*, you sure it's not what you wanted ? Well if not, please try re-explain completely your problem ...